# Derivative of arcsin problem

Tags: calculus

In my high school mathematics class, we've been taught that
$$\frac d{dx}\arcsin(x) = \frac 1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
I've gone and done my own calculus and found a completely different derivative
$$x=\arcsin(y)$$
Make $y$ the subject:
$$\therefore y = \sin(x)$$
Take the derivative:
$$\therefore \frac {dy}{dx} = cos(x)$$
Take the reciprocal:
$$\therefore \frac {dx}{dy} = \frac 1{\cos(x)}$$
Sub in the original equation:
$$\frac d{dy}(\arcsin(y)) = \frac 1{\cos(x)}$$
But that's not what I was taught in class. What's wrong with my calculation?

Comment: Nothing's really wrong, but your answer for $d/dy$ is in terms of $x$.  Put it in terms of $y$ and you should find that you get the right answer.

Comment: Well, in your last formula the left-hand side involves only $y$ and the right-hand side involves only $x$.  This isn't wrong, merely useless.  If you re-write the right-hand side in terms of $y$ you will recover what you were taught.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with your answer, the only "error" is that the right-hand side is in terms of $x$ while the left-hand side is in terms of $y$. Although this can be easily corrected.

The more systematic approach that you learn in school is to consider $y$ as the function you want to differentiate$$y=\arcsin x\qquad\implies\qquad \sin y=x$$And implicitly differentiate to get$$y'_x\cos y=1\qquad\implies\qquad y'_x=\frac 1{\cos y}=\frac 1{\sqrt{1-\sin^2y}}=\frac 1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
Which is essentially the same as your method, but the variables are just swapped.

Answer (score 1):

To make this explicit: $$\frac{1}{\cos(x)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2(x)}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}$$

Comment: i think you meant $\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}$ in the segond part :v